# Unable to add images to mdx file in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-remark-image

I am trying to import an image into an mdx file by doing this: `![alt](image.jpg)`. My mdx file and image are both stored in the directory src, posts, post-1. However, the image does not display. I've tried numerous file paths with no luck.

The only way I've been able to get images to display is by using src e.g. `![alt](/static/47d93fd9bdeaaf54a7b60d14c66abe5d/48e00/icon.jpg)`

Below is part of my gatsby.config

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `post-featured`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/post-featured/`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
      options: {
        root: __dirname,
        extensions: [".md", ".mdx"],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 800,
              quality: 70,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to reference the images as a relative path starting with `./`, e.g. `![alt](./image.jpg)`

It's not particularly clear in the documentation but mentioned in https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/#usage-in-markdown

Answer (score 1):

I have worked my way around this issue by adding an images array to my blog post mdx frontmatter e.g. `images: [formby-golf-club.jpg, myFirstTweet.PNG]`.

Then in my post template I grab the publicURL of the images in the array via graphQL, and pass them into MDXRenderer, like so: `<MDXRenderer images={data.mdx.frontmatter.images}>`.

I can then access the images array in my mdx file like this: `<img src={props.images[0].publicURL} style={{ width: "100%" }} />`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after reading [official how-to guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/#using-the-mdx-plugin) and adding `gatsby-remark-image` as a single entry in plugins array. Keeping it only inside `gatsby-plugin-mdx` solved the issue for me.